# Как поменять значение в первой строке датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу поменять значение в объеме фасовки только у одного значения, не используя дату, но при таком написании

```
graphic.loc[(graphic['Пункт отгрузки']=='ПНОС') & (graphic['Код КССС']==207465), 'Объем_фасовки, т'][0] = 0
```

ничего не меняется

Comment: а что у вас за индекс [0] в самом конце? он для чего?

Comment: без этого индекса возвращает две записи, но мне нужно поменять только в первой, поэтому поставила этот индекс

Comment: Ну вот потому правила сайта и обязуют приводить в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных. чтобы не гадать

Comment: согласна, в следующий раз прикреплю вывод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы присваиваете 0 не ячейке в датафрейме, а значению, из него полученному. Если уж вы хотите делать именно таким способом, то такая монструозная конструкция вам должна помочь:

```
df.loc[df.loc[(df['Пункт отгрузки']=='ПНОС') & (df['Код КССС']==207465), 'Объем_фасовки, т']
       .idxmin(), "Объем_фасовки, т"] = 0
```